# Playing a .wav file using naudio, playback stops after 1 sec

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

I'm using the naudio lib in C# and want to play a simple file. The problem is, the playback stops after 1 second. I cant figure out the reason why it does that.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NAudio.Wave;

namespace NAudioTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static IWavePlayer waveout;
        static WaveStream outputStream;
        static string filename = null;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            waveout = new WaveOut();

            filename = "C:\\1.wav";

            outputStream = CreateInputStream(filename);

            try
            {
                waveout.Init(outputStream);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error while loading output");
                Console.WriteLine("Details: " + ex.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to start playback");
            Console.ReadLine();

            waveout.Play(); //this stops after 1 sec. should it play until i hit enter cause of the next line?

            Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to abort");
            Console.ReadLine();
            waveout.Dispose();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        static WaveStream CreateInputStream(string name)
        {
            WaveChannel32 inputStream;
            if (name.EndsWith(".wav"))
            {
                WaveStream readerStream = new WaveFileReader(name);
                if (readerStream.WaveFormat.Encoding != WaveFormatEncoding.Pcm)
                {
                    readerStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(readerStream);
                    readerStream = new BlockAlignReductionStream(readerStream);
                }

                if (readerStream.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample != 16)
                {
                    var format = new WaveFormat(readerStream.WaveFormat.SampleRate, 16, readerStream.WaveFormat.Channels);
                    readerStream = new WaveFormatConversionStream(format, readerStream);
                }
                inputStream = new WaveChannel32(readerStream);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid extension");
            }
            return inputStream;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing `"Press [Enter] to abort"` when it starts playing?

Comment: Could use `System.Media.SoundPlayer` unless you're using a demo app to proof code for a bigger application.

Comment: sorry in the code was piece of debug code what i have tested, i correct it.  @mark, yes i see it while i plays the 1second.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make sure you are using function callbacks if you are trying to play audio from a console app, since the default for WaveOut is to use window callbacks.

```
new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback())
```

**Update:** With newer versions of NAudio I now recommend that you avoid function callbacks, as they can cause deadlocks with certain drivers. Instead, `WaveOutEvent` which uses event callbacks and a background thread is the preferred mechanism:

```
new WaveOutEvent()
```