# The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist

Tags: c#, linq, compiler-errors

While fiddling with Naudio, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391409/playing-a-wav-file-using-naudio-playback-stops-after-1-sec) code. I am compiling it as:

```
csc.exe /reference:Naudio.dll play.cs
```

and getting the error:

> play.cs(3,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in
>               the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The version of csc is: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.EXE

While searching for it, I found a thread which says I need to add `System.core` reference, but doing something like: `/reference:System.core.dll` or `/reference:System.core` is not solving the problem.

Comment: Use the compiler from .NET 3.5 or .NET 4.0 and the code will compile as is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

version `v2.0.50727` does not natively supports `Linq`. To solve your issue, you can try these two methods:

1. Remove reference to `Linq` if possible (as already suggested by SS Kain).
2. If removing `Linq` is not desirable for you, use the higher version.
   Instead of using csc from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.EXE`, I would suggest upgrading to the latest .NET version (provided your deployment doesn't have issues with that) and try using `csc.exe` from there.

   I use `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\` and that works fine for me.

   Also note that if you are using Visual Studio 2010 command prompt, this path is not added by default to your PATH env variable and so you will have to add it manually.

   `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\`

Comment: When I browse and add C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe and then hit add it says A reference to C:\Windows\......could not be added. No types or libraries were found in the component. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I believe that `2.0.50727` does not support `Linq`, remove `Linq` from references and from "usings" and hope that there are no `Linq` statements in the code

Answer (score 2):

Linq is not part of the .NET Framework 2, which you are using. Try a newer version instead.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should remove

```
using System.Linq;
```

from the top of the file play.cs, since this reference is not available in .Net 2.0, which you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I had a reference to System.Xml.Linq and still got an error.

The solution for me was:

1. Swap .net ver to 2.0
2. Rebuild (fails)
3. Swap .net ver to 3.5(in my case),
4. Rebuild (works).